# How To Create Animated Onboarding on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, core-animation

I'm creating an app that will have a quick onboarding at the beginning with some pretty simple scroll through animations and finish with a button to basically "GO" into the app's content.

I'm looking for suggestions as for how to most effectively and efficiently develop this, here's some things that it needs:

- there should be paging so that it locks onto about 4 different positions throughout the onboarding.
- the animations progress should be dependent on the scroll view's position (I'm guessing the x value of the content offset)
- there needs to be views that stay on screen through multiple pages and some that move on screen and off screen throughout the onboard, it can not just be one picture moving on then off
- there needs to be a button that pops up on the last page

I have a good understanding of Scroll Views, Page Views, and Page Controls. I also just bought Core Animator (the app) if anyone can suggest how implement that.

The way that I'm thinking of doing it is basically creating a Scroll View with paging that is empty and just use it to control animations with its content offset. Is there a faster way to do this or maybe a open source library that would work better? I'm only proficient in Swift currently :?

Thanks for any suggestions! This my first app and I'm very excited to hear your suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by "onboarding"?

Comment: Like a tutorial at the beginning so that a user will understand how the app works. You're trying to get the user "onboard" with your app

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 0):

I would look at `UIPageViewController` as its setup to do the scrolling by page for you, although you have control over what kind of animation it uses.  You are responsible for feeding it view controllers to display using this method:

`setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)`

here is the link to the apple documentation [UIPageViewController docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im worried about losing too much control if I use UIPageViewController instead of a UIScrollView but I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

I created a scrolling credits screen for one of my company's apps, FaceDancer, that would be a decent starting point for what you are after. The app is free. You can download it to check it out at this link: [FaceDancer](http://www.tinyurl.com/facedancer). The credits screen is off the info button on the main screen.

It's not hard to use UIView animations to simply animate a series of views. I think that might be easier than working with a scroll view.

I can give you some guidance if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks duncan, I checked out the app you mentioned, the credits page was very well done. Unfortunately, I need the user to be in control throughout the process, not the device. If you think of something that would be more suited for that I would find your advice very helpful!

Comment: I'm envisioning a custom set of view animations driven by a pan gesture recognizer that's attached to the main view controller's content view. As the user slides his finger you'd move the animation through it's progress. The credits animation you looked at had multiple steps where the animation sped up and slowed down. You could insert pauses into yours using different delay amounts on the various parts.

Comment: Once you've submitted an animation you can pause it and scrub it backwards/forwards by manipulating the animation settings on the parent view's layer. I have a demo app on github that shows how to do that.

Comment: @DuncanC do you have a link to the demo app please?

Comment: Check out this Github repo: https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations.git

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk